# Extract module name and instance name from verilog/System Verilog file

Tags: awk, grep, perl, text-formatting

I have a verilog/System Verilog file from which I want to extract only module_name and instance_name.

From following single line:

module_name #(.ANY_PARAMETER(.ANY_PARAMETER),.ANY_PARAMETER_1(.ANY_PARAMETER_1)) instance_name (.any_connection(any_connection));

the output should be only:

module_name instance_name

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

We need `recursive regex` to handle such cases of balanced + nested braces.

We first craft a regex `$r` which begins a bracket '(', then looks for non brackets stuff (may not be there because of *), then recurse, non bracketed stuff once more and finally the balancing closing bracket.

```
$ perl -lne '
    $r = qr/\( [^()]* (?:(??{ $r }) [^()]*)* \)/x;
    print $1 =~ y/\t #//dr while /\G([^()]*) $r/xg;
' file.sv
```

**Results:**

```
module_name
instance_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Command
.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (($i ~ /module/)||($i ~ /instance/)) print $i}}' filename
```

output

```
module_name
instance_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file appears to follow these rules:

- Every line contains exactly three spaces.
- The module name is whatever comes before the first space.
- The instance name is whatever comes between the second and third spaces.

If that isn’t right, please edit your question
to give a better explanation and better examples.

#### sed

Use a `sed` **s**ubstitute (`s`) command to match the entire line,
with a capture group running from the beginning of the line
up through the first space, and a second capture group
running from the second space to the third one (excluding the endpoints). 
Then output the two captured strings:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]* \)[^ ]* \([^ ]*\) .*/\1\2/'
```

P.S. If there are actually more than three spaces,
and the instance name is between the second-to-last and the last one,
change to this:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]* \).* \([^ ]*\) .*/\1\2/'
```

#### pcregrep

Same logic, different tool:

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 '^([^ ]* )[^ ]* ([^ ]*) .*'
```

`-o1 -o2` is equivalent to `\1\2`.

The same postscript applies.